# How to split a list of integers to smaller chunks?

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a list of integers with 50 items:

```
List<int> list = CreateList();
```

How could I split it into chunks of 9 items?

```
List<List<int>> chunks = CreateChucks(list);
```

I've written this, is there any better way?

```
private static List<List<T>> GetChunks<T>(List<T> list, int maxChunkSize = 1000)
    {
        var chunks = new List<List<T>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i = i + maxChunkSize)
        {
            chunks.Add(list.Skip(i).Take(maxChunkSize).ToList());
        }

        return chunks;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use `Batch` operator of [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) (available from NuGet):

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> chuncks = list.Batch(9);
```

If you want list of lists, then you can create own extension:

```
public static List<List<T>> Batch(this IEnumerable<T> source, int batchSize)
{
    List<List<T>> result = new List<List<T>>();
    List<T> batch = new List<T>(batchSize);

    foreach(T item in source)
    {
        if (batch.Count == batchSize)
        {
            result.Add(batch);
            batch = new List<T>(batchSize);                 
        }

        batch.Add(item);
    }

    if (batch.Any())
       result.Add(batch);

    return result;        
}
```

Your current implementation has big drawback - `list.Skip(i)` will enumerate source list from beginning for each batch you are adding to result.

Comment: @CodeCaster let it stay here :) I also added explanation why current implementation is not very good. Btw it's better to move this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ because OP already has implementation

Comment: I like your solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var list = new List<int>();
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    list.Add(i);

var chunk = new List<List<int>>();
var chunkSize = list.Count / 9;
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    var p = list.Skip(i * chunkSize).Take(chunkSize).ToList();
    chunk.Add(p);
}
```